# Show/hide text box on check/uncheck of a checkbox in richfaces 4

Tags: javascript, xhtml, richfaces, el

I was working in Richfaces 4 where i had a requirement that, there's a checkbox & if someone checks it, the boolean value should be stored in a boolean variable in the backing bean without the form being submitted. And according to the value of that variable in backing bean, a text box should be rendered.
The coding is somewhat like this:-

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="test" onclick="jsRender()" onchange="document.getElementById('formName:test').checked == true ? #{bean.setChecked(true)} : #{bean.setChecked(false)}" />

<a4j:jsFunction name="jsRender" render="@form" />

<h:inputText id="textBox" value="bean.Something" rendered="#{bean.checked}"/>
```

As far as I know, until the form is submitted, the value of checkbox is not stored in the backing bean. But since I need it to change before Form submission, I have used that condition in the 'onchange' attribute. But the problem is that, the ternary condition is not getting executed, only the el expressions are executing, so I am getting a true as well false no matter if i 'check' or 'uncheck'. I think the syntax is wrong. I need help with the correct syntax.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can call ajax in `a4j:jsFunction`. For that purpose use `action` attribute of `a4j:jsFunction`.

Comment: Submitting a form is the only way you can get your value to the server. What else are you submitting that you need the value "before submitting".

Comment: Thanks @Vasil Lukach, I solved the issue. I just used `execute="@this"` & `render` attribute of `a4j:ajax` to submit only that particular `s:div` so that the value gets updated in the backing bean without submission of the whole form.

Comment: @Makhiel there are a lot of other components and elements which I don't want to submit before the user 

completes filling all the `required` fields. That's why I needed an `ajax` call to submit a particular element. 

Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Shouvik post your answer and accept it. It will be indicator that question is already answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue I used something like this :-

```
<selectBooleanCheckbox id="test" value="bean.something">
<a4j:ajax event="change" render="div_name" execute="@this">
</selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

And this solution worked for me.